# What is the "thing" that produce radio waves

Tags: rf

From the best of my knowledge, radio signals are generated through some "oscillating" device and are propagated through an antenna.

The signal transmits throughout vacuum and experience some attenuation in dense media.

The receiver which is another antenna has a filter that picks up the frequency.

The peaks of the wave represents a "1" and the valley of the wave represents a "0", this is interpreted as digital signals by a processor and generates the corresponding results.

Can someone elaborate as to what is this oscillating thing that produce radio signal in modern radio device. Is it some sort of crystal or some elaborate circuit?

Comment: This is a really broad question. There are many different ways to make an oscillator. Google "oscillator circuit", read what you find, and then let us know if you have a specific question.

Comment: Also what you wrote about peaks representing 1s and troughs representing 0s is wrong. What you're talking about is called "modulation" and although there are many many kinds of modulation, all of them require one or more cycles of the carrier frequency per bit when used in RF.

Comment: Transmitting system defined as a production of well-behaved accelerated charges, that after some amplification, leaking out.

Comment: *"signal transmits throughout vacuum"* Hmm, I think we'd have a little trouble breathing if that was the case.

Comment: Maybe you should read some introductory article like [this](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/radio.htm) to clear up some of your misunderstandings.

Then you could try with this more complex [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio) on the same topic.

This other Wikipedia article on [electronic oscillators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_oscillator) may give you some more information on the specific question you have.

Comment: After you have cleared your mind on the topic, feel free to post a more specific question, following the guidelines of this site. As someone pointed out already, as it stands your question is too broad.

Comment: Also, the peaks don't correspond to 1, and the valley's to 0.  A radio transmission has to be actually modulated in some form to convey data.  Alone, you just have a single frequency carrier wave doing pretty much nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all modern radio transmitters indeed use one or more crystals to generate the transmit frequency and other needed frequencies. As crystals are only available / practical up to a relatively low frequency  a circuit called a [PLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop) is used to convert the crystal's frequency up to the required transmit frequency.

Another way to generate high frequencies is by using a tuned cavity, similar to the [magnetron tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavity_magnetron) used in microwave ovens.

It depends on the application which solution is chosen.

Answer (score 0):

The "thing" that creates the oscillation is called an **oscillator**. There are many different types of oscillators. They all have in common that they consist of

- a part that resonates at a certeain frequency (or suppresses other than the wanted frequency; e.g. a crystal or a LC- or RC-circuit)
- a part that takes care that the oscillation does not die out because of "friction" (resistance), i.e. an amplifier (e.g. single transistor or OpAmp)